# Autocomplete in Netbeans

Tags: autocomplete, netbeans-7

I use Netbeans 7.2.1, when I type `private String a`(Java code), the IDE shows a tip window `aString` which asks me to name a variable with its type as postfix. In addition, when I continue to type `;`, it completes the code with `private String aString;`. Actually, I do not like this naming style, so, how to change the settings?

Answer (score 45):

## For windows :

1. Go to Tools `>` Options `>` Editor `>` Code Completion
2. Select Language Java from dropdown
3. Auto pop-up on typing any Java identifier part

---

You can take help from the images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the default values (.;->;.*;->*;::;new ;) set for triggers and the check-box for "auto Insert #include Directives". These values do not work with defined variables and functions. Is there a way for code assistant to also pop for variables and functions? The variable does appear in the list when I key in ctrl + space.

Answer (score 17):

Under `Preferences -> Editor -> Code Completion` is where you can find the auto complete properties. You can disable the 'Auto Popup Completion Window' to keep it from automatically popping.

You can bring up the auto complete popup with the hotkey: `control+space`

Also while the completion window is displayed, pressing the `esc` will close it without inserting an autocomplete value.

Answer (score 5):

Go to: Preferences -> Editor -> Formatting.

In the drop-down box "Language", choose "Java".

There are many other categories you can choose from and you can customize your code formatting style there.

Comment: any details? I do not wanna close the tip, just ignore this type of tips