# Unable to resolve name identifier in netbeans IDE 8.2

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8.2

It shows the build is successful and even displays the output but it gives me a red flag which states "Unable to resolve identifier name" for the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include<typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto num = 10;
    cout<<typeid(num).name(); //Red Flag out here (a bulb with red ! mark) and name() is underlined with red color.
    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is:
i

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330926/autocomplete-in-netbeans

Comment: This Doesn't work. I already tried

Comment: Well, if in simpler expressions the intellisense works, then it's broken.

Comment: I have just downloaded netbeans IDE 8.2 for c++ and is up-to-date.