# Intellisense for userdefined classes in java in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am confused that how to make intellisense of userdefined classes in java. When we make the object of one class into another, it gives me all the methods and attributes of the first class alongwith some other methods like toString() of object class. So how to make intellisense of the first class?

Comment: Any class you define in Java automatically inherits the Object class.  This is why your class has methods such as toString().

Answer (score 0):

I  have tried netbeans for many of my projects and it have quite good code completion and intellisense for user defined classes and methods also .
Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330926/autocomplete-in-netbeans) thread to enable it for java.

If the problem still persists then may be you should try to delete your NetBeans cache, which should be located in -

> $HOME/.netbeans/$VERSION/var/cache/

But create a backup first .

After this ,  you can  try creating a new project to kickstart NB cache .

Also there is a similar  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873432/netbeans-php-code-completion-for-own-code)  but the language is php  , try those solutions also.